# Rotation as conceptualization: what would be an intuitive illustration of varimax vs quartimax?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, factor-rotation

I am trying to find an *intuitive* illustration -- particular of `varimax`and `quartimax` -- to inform the choice of rotation (in the context of a principal components analysis).

I am aware of the *formal* definition of the two, and [these](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185216/factor-rotation-methods-varimax-oblimin-etc-what-do-the-names-mean-and-wh) [two](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/151653/what-is-the-intuitive-reason-behind-doing-rotations-in-factor-analysis-pca-how/151688#151688) formidable answers on the topic.

In short, `varimax` maximizes the variance of loadings on each *component* (column-wise, so to speak), whereas `quartimax` minimizes the number of high-loading components on each *variable* (row-wise, so to speak).
In other words, `varimax` "explains" *components* with maximally varying *variables*, whereas `quartimax` "explains" *variables* with as few components as possible.

The way I understand rotation procedures, they are a way to **make loadings matrices human-readable**, much like concepts in general make the world human-readable. (For example, the concept "friendliness" is a way to make the manifold variations of human behaviours intelligible).

Now I suggest that `varimax` and `quartimax` (as well as other rotation procedures) can be understood as *alternative logics* (?) to formulate such concepts.

I'd like to find a *good example* to illustrate this **rotation-as-concept-formulation**.

My first attempt at such an illustrative example is this:

- let us take an example of **Q-Mode PCA** on foods, where **dishes are variables** (say, a BLT-sandwhich, a curry, ...), and **food characteristics are cases** (say, salt content, calories, etc.).
- let the points in the below *loadings plot* (not biplot!) be *dishes (variables)*, as they are correlated with other dishes *across various food characteristics (as cases)*.
- assume further that we're only *retaining the first two components* from a PCA over various dishes
- the *red* axes are the axes as "drawn" by `varimax`, with variables often loading *high on both components* (many variable-points are in the *corners* of the plot)
- the *green* axes are the axes as "drawn" by `quartimax`, with variables often loading *high* on only *one* component (many variable-points are on/close to the *axes* of the plot).

[image: First draft of an illustrative]

I have tried to *label* (interpret) these fictitious axes in a meaningful way; maybe `varimax` components would be `warm-cold`, `sweet-hearty/savory`, whereas `quartimax` components would be `lunch-dinner`, `domestic-foreign`.

Under `varimax`-rotation, dishes would then be conceptualized in what might (preliminarily) be called **clear-cut, abstract terms**: any given dish will likely vary strongly along these dimensions (it's rare to have a dish that you're eating *somewhat* warm, and that is somewhere *in-between* sweet and savory).
On the other hand, it's not really clear what a *savory* dish would be, that is not *also* either hot or cold (there are few dishes *on the axes*).

Conversely, under `quartimax`-rotation, dishes would be conceptualized in a more **mushy, but authentic way**: any given dish may be somewhere along the domestic-foreign continuum (say, a pizza hawaii in Italy), but the *extremes* of the axes *do* make sense: there is, conceivable, such a thing as a *foreign* dish (say, sushi), that is neither lunch nor dinner.
The axes, are, in other words, occupied, including at the extremes.

**Both** conceptualizations of dishes, naturally, make sense, but in a different way: `quartimax` emphasizes categories that can *actually be observed in pure form*, whereas `varimax` emphasizes categories that are maximally distinct.

Now, my **questions**:

1. Did I get `varimax`, `quartimax` approximately right? **Does this make sense**?
2. Can you help me come up with **a better example**?
3. In particular, can you help me come up with an **example in R-mode PCA** (not Q-mode)? (I'm used to Q, and couldn't help wrap my head around in R-mode, but that should make this more generally meaningful).
4. **Bonus**: How would alternative rotation methods figure in this example: `equamax` and `parsimax` (let's stick to *orthogonal* procedures for now ...).

Comment: At the moment I've not time to do nice explanations here. But as I've seen in your profile that you're in Bremen I've just uploaded an old text of mine which might give at least some introductory, but pretty systematic insight into the problem of rotation. See http://go.helms-net.de/stat/fa/IR_MethodenManual.doc  It is really amateurish and intended as a handbook for my self-programmed factor analytic tool "inside-[r]". The part of quartimax and varimax could be much improved, but embedded in the whole text it might so far at least give an improved idea/intuition. I can come back to this later

Comment: thanks for pointing me to that excellent, rigorous and highly technical manual of yours @GottfriedHelms!
I hadn't fully comprehended the geometric perspective on rotation yet.
I am, however, still unsure what especially varimax vs quartimax mean in *conceptual* terms (see above), and would appreciate any thoughts you might have.

Comment: also @GottfriedHelms, I have a small question (somewhat of an aside): I hadn't heard of centroid *rotation* before, but just of the centroid *factor extraction procedure*, which seems to have similar features (indeterminacy, reflections, etc.). 
Am I correct to assume that centroid rotation is the "default" (unrotated) result from centroid extraction, just as the principal components "rotation" is the "default" (unrotated) result from PCA extraction?

Comment: Well I've taken that "centroid"-thing from two old books (Ueberla[1968],Mulaik[1972]) and it may be they wrote only of "centroid extraction" and not of "~rotation", perhaps my wording is a bit inaccurate here. But it can be implemented by a rotation (and I did it in the program) and so I might have over-generalized the book-texts (not the method itself). Hmm. About the "conceptual difference" - roughly said: varimax maximizes variance (around a floating mean in the loadingssquares of each factor over the iterations) while quartimax works without relating to such a factor-specific mean.