# factor loadings vs pca loading difference?

Tags: pca, factor-analysis

What is the difference between factor loadings and PCA loadings? I can't seem to have a definitive explanation of the difference.

Comment: Can you see a difference between factors and PCs? This is the main difference. Also, check out some excellent posts like [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/119746) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143905/); there are more, just search for them.

Comment: The difference between the loadings boil down to a difference in how EFA and PCA are conceptualized. I have an answer on this here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/280746/what-is-the-difference-between-pca-and-paf-method-in-factor-analysis/280861#280861. It specifically asks about the PAF method for factor loadings, but it applies to any EFA.