# Does Quartimax rotation really maximize the variance of rows in the loading matrix?

Tags: multivariate-analysis, factor-analysis, factor-rotation

The textbook I'm currently reading says that the quartimax rotation in the factor analysis maximizes the rows' variance in the loading matrix.

In order to do that, it says, the quartimax rotation maximizes Q, described below. (row no i and col no j).

But about that Q, isn't it the same even if you switch the first sigma with the second one?

If it's the same, isn't the size of Q affected by both the columns and rows' variance?

I really don't understand why quartimax rotation, using Q, maximizes only the variance of rows.

I would really appreciate any help!

[image]

Comment: Incorrect. Not maximizing row variances but maximizes row simplicity. I.e., ideally each row (variable) having only one big loading. Power 4 is to maximize kurtosis, that is, produce fat tail of small loadings.

Comment: Quartimax maximizes variances of _squared_ loadings in rows. It can be shown that this is mathematically equivalent to the simplification noted in the previous comment.

Comment: Thx for comment. You know where I can see that demonstration?

Comment: In classic books on Factor analysis. Such as Harman's or Mulaik's

Comment: Please check this updated answer https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/185245/3277